# What is the difference between "full" and "ultimate" trust?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, web-of-trust

When you `trust` a GnuPG key, you can choose one of these five options (and I'm assuming the same options exist in other OpenPGP tools):

> 1 = I don't know or won't say (**undefined**)
>    2 = I do NOT trust (**never**)
>    3 = I trust **marginally**
>    4 = I trust **fully**
>    5 = I trust **ultimately**

If you look at the options as "variables" used for "calculating" validity, **never**, **marginal**, and **full** are all clear. However, if so, I'm not sure how **ultimate** fits into the picture during the calculations.

What is the difference between the last two in the list?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Ultimate trust means that the key is allowed as introducer** in the web of trust. This means, if a key is ultimately trusted, all certified keys are considered valid, no matter if there is a trust path to the ultimately trusted key. This does *not* require you to posses the private keys, but you usually will do.

**Full trust** (by default, this can be adjusted) also makes keys certified by the fully trusted key considered trusted, **if and only if the fully trusted key is valid itself** (thus, there is a certification path from an ultimately trusted key).

**Marginal trust** works similar to full trust, but requires **multiple incoming certifications** from other marginally valid keys.

Answer (score -3):

Ultimate means you have the private key. In terms of calculating the web of trust relationships, full and ultimate have the same weight.